# Pausing a thread from another one: how to or alternatives

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm facing a problem. I have a Java client-server application that manages a restaurant; I need to use just keyboard input and output in order to manage it.
My waiter class has two threads: one that reads orders from the input, and one that is continuatively listening (using multicast) for a ready dish that needs to be delivered to the table.
Considering that everything is meant to be done with keyboard, my "ordering" thread writes to standard output "Do you wanna make an order? [y/n]" and waits for an answer, while the "delivery" thread listens for something to be delivered.
If the waiter chooses to order something, then the second thread doesn't show anything until the order is finished (done using a status boolean); if the waiter is free (which means, is showing the hint: "Do you wanna order?") and a ready dish arrives he will see on standard input "There is something to be delivered. Wanna deliver it? [y/n]" and wait for an answer.
My problem is that, whatever he chooses, I don't have any control on which thread will read the answer: did he mean to deliver or to order?
I've tried many possibilities, everyone not working:
- closing the ordering scanner from input, but it can't close;
- pausing the first thread from the other one, but you can't do that in Java;
- synchronizing everything, not working because the threads are meant to work together, not one at a time;
- use some semaphores/status boolean, but in that case I need to modify all the "ordering" part, including an infinite loop that checks that semaphores (I can't use acquire or release without stopping everything).
Any ideas/hints on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you sure threads are the right thing to use to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please format your post? It's hard to read such a blob of text.

Comment: @immibis if you have any hint, you are welcome. at the moment, that is the only thing I could think of

Comment: @tenik Do not use threads unless you really know what you're doing. You don't really know what you're doing, so don't use threads. Getting threads to co-operate the way you want them to is really really hard. (Non-co-operating threads, like threads that do some heavy processing independent of any other thread, then set a result, then exit, are okay)

Answer (score 0):

Have one thread and only one thread listening to UDP.  It can store the results in a thread safe collection for the keyboard thread to read or wait on.

Comment: But my problem is not that, my problem is that when I have to do something with the keyboard, I have two threads listening to it at the same time, which means that I don't know which one will read my input; I can't synchronize it due to the nature of my problem.

Comment: @tenik ok, have one and only one thread reading from the keyboard, and one and only one thread listening to UDP.

Comment: Humans are single threaded, if they are asked from two things, they don't know which thing they are answering.